# Document.write nondestructive alternative

Tags: javascript, document.write

I'm currently using this to relocate an element if the user accesses the page via portrait mode:

```
<script>if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){ document.write('<div id="bigdiv2" style="position:relative; top: 70px; left: -410px;">');}
</script>
Element
<div>
```

However, due to the destructive nature of document.write aswell as other scripts taking precedence,
this completely overwrites the page onload.

Is there a better alt. (append ?) to make this work ?

Comment: Yes, there are better alternatives.

Comment: Use DOM operations like `document.getElementById("someID").innerHTML = '...'`